# Calling Nest REST API on from android app without using Firebase SDK

Tags: android, rest, dex, nest-api

Including Firebase.jar file in my android app project will cause reaching 64k dex limit. So, I'd like to use REST API instead of Firebase API.

After I got access token, I try to use either HttpPut or HttpsURLConnection to change thermostat mode. By using HttpsURLConnection, I got http response code 307 to ask me to redirect to firebase-apiserverN url. Then, I use the new URL and do a HttpsURLConnection PUT, I got http response code 400.

Is there any Nest API sample code for android without Firebase? Thanks.

Comment: How many method calls are in the Firebase.jar? Your best solution might be to have multiple `.dex`s. There is a great blog post on how to do that here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html